# Why is the non-greedy Pattern greedy?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

```
import re
from textblob import TextBlob

f = open('G:/temp1/words.srt')
fp = open('G:/temp1/words1.txt','w')

pattern = re.compile(r'/NN.+? .+?/VB/B-VP.+? .+?/NN')

for line in f:
    blob = TextBlob(line)
    for sentence in blob.sentences:
        if re.search(pattern, sentence.parse()):
            print(sentence, file=fp)
            print(sentence.parse(), file=fp)

f.close()
fp.close()
```

Input:

```
 dogs eat bones. 
 it's a performance they put on at her school
```

result:

```
 dogs eat bones.

dogs/NNS/B-NP/O eat/VB/B-VP/O bones/NNS/B-NP/O ././O/O

 it's a performance they put on at her school

it/PRP/B-NP/O '/POS/O/O s/PRP/B-NP/O a/DT/I-NP/O performance/NN/I-NP/O they/PRP/I-NP/O put/VB/B-VP/O on/IN/B-PP/B-PNP at/IN/I-PP/I-PNP her/PRP$/B-NP/I-PNP school/NN/I-NP/I-PNP
```

question:

I want to get the line1-2(dogs eat bones), but the line3-4 was also selected. why?

Comment: Non-greedy modifiers have no impact at all on whether a pattern matches, only the *length* of the match. Can you ask a clearer question?

Comment: The second line is also matched because of *backtracking*: when the pattern fails, the engine backtracks and then tries with a *larger* capture-possibility for the `+?` part... and then it may still find a match.

Answer (score 1):

`.` matches anything, so yeah, both lines match that RE.

If you want to prevent `NN.+?` from matching more than one token, you would need to use something that says "anything but spaces" instead of "anything".

Using `NN\S+` works, and then you don't need to `?`:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'/NN\S+ \S+/VB/B-VP\S+ \S+/NN')
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8N6yKW/2

Compare with your original RE: https://regex101.com/r/EpFo5i/1

Comment: Wow, it's working. let me see what's the root cause. thanks a lot.

Comment: Here, I added capture groups to my demo link for your RE, which turns on highlighting showing you what each "token" ends up matching: https://regex101.com/r/y6Z6gy/1 It illustrates how the second NN group swallows up all the tokens between the VB and the NN because `.*?` is allowed to accept spaces too.